# call x86 winapi function in x64 process

Tags: c++, x86, 64-bit, system-calls, dll-injection

so i'm currently creating a dll injector which is x64 and able to inject into a x86 or x64 process. one part of manual mapping is fixing the import address table, which can be done by calling 'GetProcAddress', which returns the function of a certain library. so here is my problem, since i'm compiling in x64 'GetProcAddress' is always returning the x64 function, eventhough i need the x86 functions if i inject into a x86 application. is there any way i can call the x86 function in my x64 program? perhaps a direct syscall or anything like that?

Comment: You can't mix x86 and x64 code in the same process.

Comment: And you can't inject an x64 DLL into an x86 process, and vice versa.

Comment: He said the injector is x64, not the injected DLL.  Try making sense of the question under the assumption the poster is correct, instead of automatically assuming the opposite.  Writing 32-bit addresses into a 32-bit DLL prior to injecting it is perfectly consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Spin up a 32 bit process and use its `GetProcAddress` then IPC (over COM?) to the 64 bit process.

Its an extra process, but its going to work!

Comment: yeah I thought that aswell, prolly what I'm going to be doing :)